# Why Same code produces different results on circleci and github Actions

Tags: bash, circleci, github-actions

I have a bash script that I am migrating from circleci to Github Actions, but it is producing different results, it seems that a pipe operation is being executed in different orders:

This one is from github actions:

```sh
FILE_IN_LAST_COMMIT=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep -Fxq "${FILE_PATH}" && echo 1 || echo 0)
+++ grep -Fxq path/to/file
+++ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
+++ echo 0
++ FILE_IN_LAST_COMMIT=0
```

This one from circleci:

```sh
# This line just creates the artifacts for changed source files:
FILE_IN_LAST_COMMIT=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | grep -Fxq "${FILE_PATH}" && echo 1 || echo 0)
+++ git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
+++ grep -Fxq path/to/file
+++ echo 1
++ FILE_IN_LAST_COMMIT=1
```

As you can see, the command is computed in different order (I do not know why), and this causes the output to be 0 in actions and 1 in circleci.

Comment: So most probably the output of `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD` differs... why didn't you check it? `seems that a pipe operation is being executed in different orders` Pipe commands are executed _concurrently_ - the order is irrelevant. With the spirit of this forum, you should have asked a question, like `Why same code produces different results on circleci and github Actions?`.

Comment: How can it differ if it is running with the exact same data? for example, `/path/to/file1.py`

Comment: `How can it differ if it is running with the exact same data?` Because the execution of the command depends on the environment. Specifically `git` command depends on `.git` directory content found in current directory or in environment variable. Example in one environment `.git` dir is present, in other not. Or one is a shallow git clone, the other has all commits. Etc.

Comment: mmm, this could be actually the a problem while checking the code with `uses: actions/checkout@master` on github actions... let me try

Comment: That was the problem!, thank you, totally missed the checkout param  fetch-depth, setting it to 0 fetch all history

Comment: Yes, kind of, the problem was with `fetch-depth`